# Chrome stops JavaScript execution without a bug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, crash, jspdf

I am working on an open source plugin for the web mapping library [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com). The idea is to generate printable PDF documents from the map directly in the client browser. It's basic functionality works, but there is an issue in Google Chrome.

Depending of the document format and dpi settings, the script can take some time to fetch all the map tiles as images, convert them to data uris and add them to the document. In this case, the Firefox user interface doesn't respond for some seconds and then it shows the finished PDF. However, Chrome stops executing the script and shows me a bad smiley.

> Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. To continue, reload or go to another page.

Normally, I would say that that is fine since there is a limitation due to processing power. But this actually happens for DIN A4 format at 300dpi, so I can't live with that. I have strong guess that this is not related to a bug in my code, because I can increase options step by step and at some level, Chrome stops executing the script.

How can I debug my code to find the bottleneck? How can I prevent Chrome from stopping my script?

Comment: This is a bug report. People at chrome's bug tracker might also be more capable of suggesting a work-around.

Comment: @sabof I haven't thought of this being Chrome bug, rather than an issue with my own code. I think that is a good idea though.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue (by yourself or though chrome bug report)? For me if my pdf is of 1 page then i am able to show the pdf in a new window (i'm using jsPDF), but if the pdf is 2 pages with second page also having images then chrome crashes. Firefox doesn't show any such issue

Comment: @Rajeev No, I couldn't solve the issue so far.

Comment: @danijar I was able to show the 2 pages by reducing down the image resolutions. All my images stretch to full width of the page, with 2 images on first page and 1 image in second page. Noticed that the url of the new pdf window was the whole base64 encoded pdf content, and it was pretty huge. So I reduced the image resolutions and size (from 2-3 MBs to 600-700 KBs), and was able to show the pdf. Might not be suitable for your case, but for me this is pretty much okay for now

Comment: @Rajeev Thanks for the details. That strengthened my assumption that the large data uri string causes the problem. I can't decrease image quality however.